# How to configure Protractor (JS) for running tests in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, microsoft-edge

I want to set my protractor.conf.js to run tests in Edge instead of in Chrome. Setting this

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge'
}
```

results in `SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService` with an error code of 199. I downloaded the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe for the version of Edge that I have from [Microsoft's website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), but I can't figure out how to tell Protractor where to find that driver. I've tried adding it to my user path, my system path, the selenium folder in protractor's node modules folder, and giving a `jvmArgs:` or `seleniumArgs:` of `['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver="<path-to-driver"']`, but I still get that SessionNotCreatedError.

I'm only writing pure JavaScript, no Java or C#, and I want all of this to be set as attributes in the protractor.conf.js file, nothing set in the actual file of tests. I have the most recent version of Node, and I'm making sure to have Edge closed when running `ng e2e`. What do I need to change or add to my config file to get this to run?

EDIT: From [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2377), I added `seleniumAddress: http://127.0.01:17556/` to my config file, but now I'm getting an `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:17556` error with error code 135. I got that address from one of the comments on that github issue, but I get the same error regardless of starting the Edge driver manually or just running `ng e2e --config <path-to-config>`.

---

**SOLUTION**
Add `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'` to the config file. Run  the edge driver manually with `webdriver-manager start --edge "<path-to-driver>\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"`, and then run `ng e2e` in another window. Thank you so much to HaC for this solution!

Comment: Try to launch the driver directly via command line to see if the issue is related to the driver or your environment.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766363/unable-to-launch-microsoft-edge-with-protractor

Comment: I did find that question in my initial research, but that question doesn't have a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reference : https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2377

1. Download and install Edge driver
2. Run `webdriver-manager start --edge "C:\path_to_the_driver\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"` . By default this will start your selenium server on port 4444 which should be open to you.
3. In your protractor config file: add `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`

Comment: I did this and it says `Selenium Server is up and running`, but how do I run my protractor tests with this? I tried opening another powershell window and running `ng e2e`, but it still tells me `SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService`.

Comment: I figured that part out, but now I'm getting this error `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:17556`

Comment: I see how my earlier answer may be confusing. Please see my edited answer. Basically you should start the server with `webdriver-manager` so you will have access to the open port and not 17556.

Comment: @Emily- Can you post a concrete steps here, as you said it's working for you. I still didn't find answer concrete. It would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: A big thanks you it works for me as well finally @Emily. I will post a concrete steps in linked question as well.

Comment: Glad to help.  @tyaga001 perhaps you can do both Emily and myself by upvoting the question and answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is not working for me at all. In my terminal when I launch the tests I am getting this error: `SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@1621b14` and in the terminal I am connecting to run the tests on I am getting `Connection reset` error. All of the other browsers are working correctly including IE. Edge is the last one giving me issues.