# Error while trying to execute protractor test script in Micro soft edge browser

Tags: protractor

Can any one help me the set up required to run the Protractor test script in Microsoft edge browser .

I have tried below steps

1. In the Protractor configuration file

   {
                               'browserName' : 'MicrosoftEdge',
                               'SharedTestFiles' : false
                           }

   seleniumArgs : ['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:/Windows/SystemApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/MicrosoftEdge.exe'],
2. run the selenium webdriver server with the below command 
     webdriver-manager start

It is displaying below error message

```
 SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService
```

Comment: Did you tried with Webdriver-Manager server?

Comment: I run the selenium server using this command webdriver-manager start . run the protractor configuration file using this command protractor protractor.conf.js --suite inbox .. Still i am getting above error message

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and worked fine for me:- 
config.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
    elementScrollBehavior: 1,
    nativeEvents: false
  },
  framework: 'jasmine',
  baseUrl: 'http://angularjs.org',
  specs: [
    'spec.js'
  ],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
}
```

Test Case/Spec file:-

```
    describe('IE Test cases suite', function() {
      it('first IE test case', function() {
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
           console.log(url);
         });
       });
    });
```

Also you can find some pre-requisites for webdriver manager refer 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2377#issuecomment-290836086

Comment: I am also using the same code you mentioned except the baseUrl : i am using "'http://localhost:4200/'"  still it is displaying same error message .

Comment: Refer below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891742/how-to-configure-protractor-js-for-running-tests-in-microsoft-edge)

You will get the better solution here.