# i have problem with protractor when i am trying to execute the test cases in Microsoft edge browser. i am getting error

Tags: javascript, protractor, jasmine2.0

i am getting this error when i am trying to execute test cases in Microsoft edge browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

download the correct edge driver from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ and double check your configuration. there are several posts that describe how to run tests with protractor on edge, e.g.: [How to configure Protractor (JS) for running tests in Microsoft Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891742/how-to-configure-protractor-js-for-running-tests-in-microsoft-edge)